# How Can I Monetize With Startapp A Libgdx Game Made With Aide

Tags: libgdx

I have created a libGDX game with the AIDE IDE Android app. The game is working fine so I will be uploading it to the Play Store to make money.

I'd like to use Startapp ads, how would I integrate it?
I Will Using Aide Premium

Comment: https://support.startapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007225767-Integrate-our-SDK

Comment: Since you've already picked Startapp ads, did you search their website about some integration tutorials? Is something they mention difficult for you to implement/understand? If so you could mention what it is, as it would help make your question more focused on the actual problem.